# how to give a src to img dynamically from a user

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to give a source to an image from the value of an input button that has a type:"file"
but the image won't appear because of the fake path that i gain from the value of the input type : value
is there an alternative way to get a source of an jpg or png (image) ??

Comment: a little bit more explanation with your code plz..

Comment: Local files? In newer browsers there's [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), but before that, there's no way to get the correct path and name of a local file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the file contents then base64 encode them and push to `src` value:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/working-with-binary-files-using-the-javascript-filereader-.html#fbid=kLaP_XSD5_E

Comment: although is a troublesome way to solve this, you better off with a request/response roundtrip

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 FileReader API. see link below or try googling how to use the API if the link below doesn't help

http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/01/24/create-thumbnail-preview-of-images-using-html5-api/

Take note that this doesn't work on IE lower than version 10 and Safari lower than version 6. For reference see: http://caniuse.com/filereader

These browsers doesn't allow users to get the correct path on the local machine for security reasons. If you really want to make this work on these browsers, you can try storing the image in your backend.

Hope it helps. Cheers!